# I need text to appear over an interactive element without disrupting that element

Tags: css, leaflet

I'm working on a mapping program right now using twitters api. It allows the user to search a term and plot all the results graphically.

What I'd like to do is have some text above the top of the map, but without it disrupting the map.

Here's an original leaflet map: http://jsfiddle.net/sowelie/3JbNY/

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JbNY/24/) has the text, but disables the map completely.

I want it to appear like this:

```
#map {z-index:-1}
.text {z-index:1}
```

but act like this

```
#map {z-index:1}
.text {z-index:-1}
```

Is such a thing even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` doesn't work if you don't have either `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` set.

http://jsfiddle.net/CCLmP/30/

```
.text {position: relative;z-index:1}
```

That solves the vanishing problem.

As for not disrupting the map, I'm afraid you're probably out of luck -- If it's on top, it's on top. If it's below, it's below. You can't have it display on top but act like it's below.

About it disabling the map entirely, if you set the `#map` to be `position: relative;` also, it fixes it :)

```
#map {
    height: 340px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just rushing and skipped that part. I figured as much, which is unfortunate. Thought I'd try my luck with the experts of SO. I'll look into some sort of title functionality with leaflet, it seems pretty flexible. Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated it to fix your secondary issue of it disabling the map entirely: http://jsfiddle.net/CCLmP/30/

Comment: Oh wow! I never thought to even try a similar z-index. Thank you so much. Are you able to explain how this works? They're on the same z-index so shouldn't the h1 tag be clickable?

Comment: I cannot explain it, no! I believe it has something to do with the map script. From a CSS perspective, the `h1` should be selectable. If you remove the map JS, set a background on the `#map`, you can see the `h1` shows above the `#map`, but is also selectable. So ... map JS :)

Comment: Fair enough! Magical tool, JS. Thanks again, and happy holidays!